# Is there any convention for the casing of C++ files?

Tags: c++

Let's say I have a class:

```
class HelloWorld {
public:
    HelloWorld();
    // ...

private:
    int x;
    // ...
}
```

Is there any convention for naming the .cpp and .h files for this class? I'm talking about naming it hello-world.h vs hello_world.h vs HelloWorld.h vs helloworld.h.

Comment: It's mostly opinion and company standards/personal preference.

Comment: Even the `.h` extension is not set in stone. Some people use `.hpp`, others no extension at all.

Comment: Nothing is set in stone. Some of my older projects have `.cc` and `.hh` files

Comment: I'm using naming convention like in Java, i.e. HelloWorld.h

Comment: Let me be politically incorrect and say that a plain lowercase `helloworld.h` is the way to go!

Comment: You are *allowed* to choose any valid name, even if it is *not* related to your class. It is your choice.
But if you are having exclusive header and source file(s) for a single class, I recommend you to use the same name because it's more readable and understandable.

Comment: @VincenzoPii you're close, but the `hpp` extension is way better, politically incorrectly speaking of course

Comment: Some common concerns: You don't know whether the filesystem will be case sensitive or case insensitive. If you develop in a case insensitive filesystem, having `A.h` and including `a.h` will work, when you move to a different computer your project won't compile... I would avoid upper case letters.

Comment: Why avoid upper letters? Just capitalize the #include if you use them? I develop on both sorts of filesystems daily.

Comment: Honestly, nobody cares.

Comment: I say make the filename match the class name as exactly as possible.  That way there's only one thing to remember instead of two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no *universal* convention for casing the C++ files. You can refer to the [Google C++ Style Guide](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.xml#File_Names), though.

Comment: Okay. Since there's no convention, maybe I will just go with the C# conventions for stuff, naming the file HelloWorld.h

Comment: Yes that is completely your call. :)

Comment: Well, I try to follow the style in "The C++ Programming Language" as closely as possible, but I just couldn't find anything about files.

Comment: There is no such naming convention rule Sir that is why you will not find. It is about your preference.

Comment: Done, couldn't do it before now.